# Weighted logarithmic Sobolev inequality

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ent{Ent}$The usual [logarithmic Sobolev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_Sobolev_inequalities) says that
$$
\Ent_\mu(f^2)\leq C\int |\nabla f|^2 d\mu
$$
where the entropy
$$
\Ent_\mu(f^2)=\int f^2 \log\left( \frac{f^2}{\int f^2 d\mu}\right) d\mu.
$$
There have been generalizations for weighted inequalities, i-e of the form
$$
\Ent_\mu(f^2)\leq C\int \omega|\nabla f|^2 d\mu
$$
for some weight $\omega(x)$, see for example [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24903851) and references therein.
However it seems that people are mostly concerned with growing weights, $1\leq \omega(x)\to+\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$ in the whole space.
For applied models that I am currently dealing with, I am interested in the opposite case of bounded domains $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ with weights $\omega(x)>0$ decaying on the boundary
$$
\omega(x)\to 0
\qquad\mbox{as }x\to\partial\Omega.
$$
(Typically $\omega(x)\sim\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)$).
I find it extremely difficult to navigate the immense bibliography on this topics, can anyone point me to a first anchor point for the specific case of vanishing weights as above? Any pointer, direction, bibliographical entry point would be extremely useful.